# HTML CSS floats not working

Tags: html, css

Can someone please help me, for some reason i am unable to get the img and p tag to be next to each other. I must be missing something really simple thank you for the help.

```css
.sec03 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img02 {
  height: 80%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.text01 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sec03">
  <img class="img02" src="images/landscape.png">
  <p class="text01">On no twenty spring of in esteem spirit likely estate. Continue new you declared differed learning bringing honoured. At mean mind so upon they rent am walk. Shortly am waiting inhabit smiling he chiefly of in. Lain tore time gone him his dear sure.
    Fat decisively estimating affronting assistance not.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should

1. Remove `display: inline-block` from all of the three classes.
2. Remove `float: left` from `.text01`
3. Add `overflow: hidden` to text
4. You will probably want to add marrgin-right to your image

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/uft4vaoc/10/

Add a width to the paragraph and the `background-color: transparent`

```
.text01 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's what i want, why do i need to change the background-color to transparent?

Comment: Because the `<p>` tag has a defaulted background color of white.

Comment: @Jack Take the `transparent` out and see for yourself